# How can i integrate OWASP ZAP with Cypress to run both together and get the Zap test Result and Owasp Zap result at the same time?

Tags: testing, automation, cypress, owasp, zap

I want to integrate OWASP ZAP and Cypress together in such a way that when I run cypress e2e test it should run the zap test as well and give me the list of vulnerabilities that are present in my application and with that the cypress test also give me the result of the working of my application!
so can anyone please provide me a guide to this thing so I can do it easily!!

Actually I found some URLs but was not able to understand those because those URL's output were different from what I wanted so got stuck there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can .. but you should run them separately. ZAP will be attacking your app and so will almost certainly break your tests. So run your Cypress tests on their own for functionality testing and then proxy them through ZAP for security testing, ignoring any Cypress test failures.
I'm not aware of a "simple" guide for you, but for help with ZAP you should ask on the ZAP User Group.

Comment: but is it possible to run both of them together means when I run the cypress test it automatically runs my zap test as well?

Comment: I dont think this will work, no. ZAP will hammer your app with attacks, this will almost certainly cause your regression tests to fail. You can safely do passive scanning but not active.